# How to get data attribute of element when click on it or it child

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, custom-data-attribute

I am making a **Table**.

```js
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target);
  console.log(e.target.dataset.item);
})
```

```css
td {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
}

span {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-item="item1"><span>1</span></td>
    <td data-item="item2"><span>2</span></td>
    <td data-item="item3"><span>3</span></td>
    <td data-item="item4"><span>4</span></td>
    <td data-item="item5"><span>5</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When I click the **BLUE PART**, I can get `data-item` attribute. But when I click the **RED PART**, I can't.

I wanna fix it, if I click `<span/>` in `<td/>`, I want to get `data-item` attribute from `<td />`.

Comment: You could use `e.target.closest("[data-item]").dataset.item`, if [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use `closest` by your child tag instead of `dataset`.

```js
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.closest("td").dataset.item);
})
```

```css
td {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
}

span {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-item="item1"><span>1</span></td>
    <td data-item="item2"><span>2</span></td>
    <td data-item="item3"><span>3</span></td>
    <td data-item="item4"><span>4</span></td>
    <td data-item="item5"><span>5</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer :)

Comment: this is the perfect answer what I found.

Answer (score 3):

Check if name of clicked element is `span` select parent of it using [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) property

```js
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  var ele = e.target.nodeName == "SPAN" ? e.target.parentNode : e.target;
  console.log(ele.dataset.item);
})
```

```css
td {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
}
span {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-item="item1"><span>1</span></td>
    <td data-item="item2"><span>2</span></td>
    <td data-item="item3"><span>3</span></td>
    <td data-item="item4"><span>4</span></td>
    <td data-item="item5"><span>5</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you listen on the whole table in the first place?

Listen only on "td" elements:

```
let cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var i=0; i < cells.length; i++) {
  let cell = cells[i];
  cell.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let element = e.target.nodeName;
    if (element === 'TD') {
      console.log(e.target.dataset.item);
    } else if (element === 'SPAN') {
      console.log(e.target.parentNode.dataset.item);
    }      
  });
}
```

I don't think setting the listener on the table matters, because in your case, it doesn't trigger the event on the table anyways.

Some styles for better inspection:

```
table {
  background-color: orange;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aleks351/p0b46wqs/6/

Comment: because in my table, `<tbody />` is dynamically rendered

Answer (score 0):

You could check for the keys in the dataset of the clicked item and if it does have some properties then use `e.target` otherwise move up one level `e.target.parentNode`:

```js
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  var el = Object.keys(e.target.dataset).length ? 
           e.target: e.target.parentNode;
  console.log(el.dataset.item);
})
```

```css
td {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
}

span {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-item="item1"><span>1</span></td>
    <td data-item="item2"><span>2</span></td>
    <td data-item="item3"><span>3</span></td>
    <td data-item="item4"><span>4</span></td>
    <td data-item="item5"><span>5</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```